# Create data by combining query results in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a 1-n relation in my models, e.g., 1 classroom - n students.

```
Classroom 1 - Joe

Classroom 1 - Tim

Classroom 1 - Julia

Classroom 2 - Bob

Classroom 2 - Alice
```

In my view I want to show a row for each classroom and a comma separated list for the students:

```
Classroom1 | Joe, Tim, Julia

Classroom2 | Bob, Alice
```

Right now, I find the records for each classroom and create the list of students and combine that to create a dictionary.

Is there a more efficient way to create this data?  Can I save the list of students with each Classroom?

Comment: Can you show some code? Add your models and view, but mostly models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example you have

```
class Classroom(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    classroom = models.ForeignKey('Classroom')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

You can easily retrieve all students for `Classroom` like that

```
class_room1 = Classroom.objects.get(id=1)
class_room1.student_set.all()
```

Comment: I would still need to loop and process all the classroom objects. Is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: I believe there is no way you can avoid that.

Comment: Okay Thank you for your answer..@ vishes_shell

Comment: @SnehaShinde if you feel that my answer covered your question you can accept it.:)